# RubyMotion: How do I call a function in the console?

Tags: rubymotion

I have two controllers - how can I call the functions in them from the console?

`(main)>`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only way I can figure out how to do this is by using the UIApplication sharedApplication class method and drilling down from there, which is pretty icky.

```
(main)> UIApplication.sharedApplication.delegate
=> #<AppDelegate:0x6c8a800 @window=#<UIWindow:0x6e71280>>
```

Unfortunately to access the window I had to add an `attr_reader :window` to my AppDelegate class to access this private variable and then drill down even further to get at the view controllers:

```
(main)> vc = UIApplication.sharedApplication.delegate.window.rootViewController
=> #<TouchesViewController:0x8c747c0>
```

Now you should be able to call any public methods on that view controller.

Answer (score 5):

I usually add a temporary global variable in the view controller to make it easier to access it from the console.

```
def viewDidLoad
  $temp_view = self
end
```

It is not pretty, but gets the job done.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time there is a hierarchy of `UIViewController`-s, and you can tap into those.  starting at the `UIWindow#rootViewController` instance, and navigating through the `childViewControllers`.  I would recommend either using `BubbleWrap` to access the window (`App.window`) or delegate (`App.delegate`).  The `SugarCube` gem, which I maintain, provides an easy way to view the view or viewController hierarchies, too - the `tree` and `tree root` commands are available in the REPL for just this purpose.